# Handle 302 status code upon HTML/JS request to server?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, http-status-code-302, oracle-jet

I'm using Require JS and Orace JET

How can we handle the 302 status code or any other status code returned by Server when the session is timeout.

Can it be configured to catch it and redirect the user to a login page upon such cases?

Comment: *302 or any other* - I'd handle the error codes as they are supposed to be handled, depending on the error code - did you want code for every possible code? including the 700's? because that would be 720

Comment: I know through the status code, but where can we handle this issue. I tired the onError of require JS but that does not seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

The status code 302 cannot be seen by RequireJS. That's just how browsers work: the browser will see 302 and automatically perform the next HTTP request. RequireJS won't know that there was a redirection.

Any HTTP status code that is an error (500, 400, etc.) will result in a module load failure and `onError` will be called.

Comment: Is there no way I can fix this. The main problem is, we have a FORM Based authentication and Login as well as Logout works fine. 
The problem comes up when the session is timeout and we request for a JavaScript/HTML resource, container returns a “302” status with login page on top of existing page.
1. The URL path is not changed to Login URL
2. Upon logging again, the previously request JavaScript is returned but the source code is printed in the browser, instead of redirecting to welcome page. 

How can this be handled?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution (that works because of luck). Take it just as an inspiration. When session in my app expires, the request is being forwarded using 302 to login page as you would expect. There are 2 main types of requests where it can happen:

- REST API call (via XMLHttpRequest)
- navigation on page that user did

For #2, the 302 poses no problem. User is simply redirected to login page.

For #1, I can somehow detect it (with some probability) because login page is on different domain that does not support CORS. The XMLHttpRequest request will simply fail with readyState equal to 0 and statusText equal to "error" (because browser will block the XMLHttpRequest to different domain). I have a "listener" (interceptor) on all my REST API calls and whenever some fails with the 0 readyState and "error" statusText, it means that session probably expired.

This is not a solution of course and cannot be used everywhere. Just an idea to think about :)